# PyQt QtreeView scrollbar overlapping header

Tags: python, css, pyqt

I've been trying to use QTreeView (instead of QListView) because I needed an horizontal header.
Furthermore, I wanted to use stylesheet to customize header colors and scrollbars.

By default, the scrollbar overlaps the header. It's a problem that have been discussed already, and the workaround seemed fine EXCEPT that even if the scrollbar is implemented to start below the header, the scrollbar background still overlaps the header.

In my case, I would like the header to be totally adjusted to the widget, and the scrollbar to start just below

Below is some code example that reproduce my issue:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class custom_treeview(QtWidgets.QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, parent, name, color):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger.NoEditTriggers)

        # set model
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setRowCount(0)
        model.setColumnCount(1)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, name)
        self.setModel(model)

        self.setStyleSheet(f"""QTreeView {{ border: 2px solid {color}; }}
        ::section {{ background-color: {color} ;border: none;font: bold 12px;}}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {{ background: {color}; }}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {{ background: {color} }}
""")


    def updateVertScrollBar(self):
        sb = self.verticalScrollBar()
        rect = sb.geometry()
        rect.setTop(self.header().height())
        sb.setGeometry(rect)

    def resizeEvent(self, e: QtGui.QResizeEvent) -> None:
        super().resizeEvent(e)
        self.updateVertScrollBar()


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setObjectName("main_win")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("""QScrollBar:vertical { background: #FFFFFF;width: 10px; } 
        QScrollBar::add-line:vertical { height: 0px; } 
        QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical { height: 0px; } 
        QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal { width: 0px; } 
        QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal { width: 0px; } 
        QScrollBar:horizontal { background: #FFFFFF;height: 10px } 
        QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical { height: 0px; background: none; } 
        QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal { width: 0px; background: none; }""")

        self.left_tree = custom_treeview(self.splitter, "left tree", "#AB1234")

        self.right_tree = custom_treeview(self.splitter, "right tree", "#4331BA")

        a = [str(i) for i in range(500)]

        for i in a:

            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setText(i)
            self.left_tree.model().appendRow(item)

        for i in a:

            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setText(i)
            self.right_tree.model().appendRow(item)




sys.argv = ['']
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_app = MyApp()
main_app.show()
app.exec()
```

The problem is:

[image: header overlapped by scrollbar]

I also want the widget to be resizable (it's the reason why there is a splitter in my example).

What should I do to get a clean behaviour?

Comment: I believe you are interested in the up-arrow style of the scroll bar as in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the scroll bar is a direct child of the scroll area, while the contents of the view (including the header) are part of its *viewport*. You cannot "extend" the header, because it would be hidden anyway by the geometry of the viewport itself.

A possible solution is to add a basic QWidget styled with the same color as a *scroll bar widget*, and ensure that it *always* has the header height. To do so, you don't need to override `resizeEvent()`, but [`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries), which is called whenever the view requires to update its internal widgets.

```py
class custom_treeview(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, color):
        # ...
        self.setStyleSheet(f"""
            QTreeView {{ 
                border: 2px solid {color}; 
            }}
            QHeaderView::section {{ 
                background-color: {color}; 
                border: none; 
                font: bold 12px; 
            }}
            QScrollBar::handle:vertical {{ 
                background: {color}; 
            }}
            QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {{ 
                background: {color}; 
            }}
            QWidget#fakeHeader {{
                background: {color}; 
            }}
            """)
        self.fakeHeader = QtWidgets.QWidget(objectName='fakeHeader')
        self.addScrollBarWidget(self.fakeHeader, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super().updateGeometries()
        self.fakeHeader.setFixedHeight(
            self.header().height() + self.frameWidth()
        )
```

Note that this is obviously a workaround, and is not a "correct" solution: for instance, if the contents are wider than the view width, the header labels will still be restricted by the viewport margins.

Comment: ty for your help. Gonna try that. That was my guess that there was no clean solution. That's also why I wanted to ask.

Comment: It does not seem to change anything at the behavior I had. I probably gonna give up on this topic since it's not a very important one.

Or do it in a more basic way by doing a QListView with a QFrame just above it

Comment: I've tested it with PyQt5 and PyQt6, it works exactly as expected, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it. Since you're going to style almost everything, try to use app.setStyle('fusion'), or eventually `self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))` in the subclass init.

Comment: Note: as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#childEvent), you should *not* add widgets to QSplitter just by using the parent argument of the child constructor. Always use `addWidget()` or `insertWidget()`. Since QSplitter would reparent the widget anyway, you can leave out that argument (or, better, make it optional as with any standard Qt widget constructor).

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I was just reproducing the pattern generated by QtDesigner.
Concerning your solution, it's my bad, I did not see your addition in the stylesheet.

I still have a weird behaviour sometimes with stylesheet where they don't seem to apply. The sample I put here is in fact inserted in a parent QTabWidget, and on the first one, the style of scrollbar is never applied. I still have to figure this out.

Comment: @ThylowZ that's a known issue (IIRC I also wrote an answer about it), sometimes the stylesheet is not fully propagated to complex children and when applying different "layers" of style sheets; a common workaround is to call `self.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())` in the init of the problematic scroll area, *after* styling it.

Comment: your workaround worked great... on this code sample only. Sadly I could not make it work on my whole app, probably due to the complexity of the App idk (that's why I wanted to try to set a global stylesheet and have a style for each QScrollBar, to see if it could make any difference).

It's not a very important thing to be honest.

Comment: @ThylowZ you can try to do the same for the app: `app.setStyleSheet(app.styleSheet()`, possibly with a single shot QTimer with a small interval that will call it right after the UI has been loaded. It should be enough to force all affected widgets to *unpolish* them.

Comment: I used a small (dirty) workaround that worked, I did not try yours, since it seemed related especially to first tab of QTabWidget: if QTabWidget is empty, I addTab a dummy QWidget and remove it just after adding the proper tab that contains the listviews. It worked, even though it's not really clean.