# PyQT customizing specific ScrollBar

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to apply different colors to my scrollbars depending on their parent QListView, and I would like to do this from "higher level" than the QListView

Question is, how to apply different styles to scrollbars in a stylesheet? For example, for a QPushButton, I'll use `QPushButton#<name>`, but what should I do for `QScrollBar` selector?

**EDIT**

You can find a code sample in the question of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222898/pyqt-qtreeview-scrollbar-overlapping-header). As shown in the linked image, the scrollbar are NOT styled accordingly to their stylesheet (no color, border)

Comment: Qt Docs: [Selector Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Comment: Thanks for linking it but I asked specifically because it was not so clear. I used this doc a lot lately.

I tried QListView#<object_name> QScrollBar and it did not work.

Comment: @ThylowZ please provide a [mre].

Comment: @ThylowZ Works perfectly fine for me. What do you mean by "did not work"? Please don't force people to guess what the problem is. Spell it all out in detail so others can attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys I sometime try to just describe as best as I can. I added a link to another question I made where the code sample I provide leads to the problem

Comment: musciamante already provided some workaround that I will try soon.